# Converting existing table with varbinary into filestream enabled table?

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I have an existing database with 70%+ data in one table with a varbinary column.  As the database keep growing (takes longer and longer to backup and restore) I think it may be beneficial to enable filestream so we can separate the relatively stable binary files from the rest of the database.

If anyone can comment on my plan:

1. Enable the Filestream feature on the SQL Server.
2. Attach a network share (for storing the filestream data) to the server
3. Create a filestream file group for the database.
4. Create a table ("file2") that is identical to the existing table ("file") with an additional ROWGUIDCOL column in the Filestream file group.
5. Insert existing data from "file" to "file2".
6. Truncate the old table "file".
7. Delete the old table "file".
8. Rename the table "file2" to "file" so existing application continue to work.
9. (Optional) shrink database then reindex

Thanks